# What does tethering to enemies do?

Tags: risk-of-rain

I found an item with the following attribute:

> Chance to tether yourself to an enemy.

[image: Chance to tether yourself to an enemy.]

When I get shooting at people, sometimes I can see this in action.  I see a green beam form between myself and the enemy.  As far as I can work out though, that's the extent of this feature.  It doesn't appear to restrict movement of either party, and if I move far enough away or kill the tethered enemy, it disappears.

Does it do anything useful?

[image: Me tethered to a green dude]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It hurts the tethered enemy for 60% of your damage per second.

I think that also applies to all enemies touched by the tether, but I'm not 100% about that.

Comment: You can see the enemy to whom you've tethered taking damage over time as little numbers float away.

Comment: I also think that the tether damages enemies touching it, [and the wiki confirms this](http://riskofrain.wikia.com/wiki/Plasma_Chain#Tactics).